# Custom 16PIN LCD pinout required for Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd

I have this custom 16 pin LCD. Could somebody please provide me with the pinout for this? I'm sure this is compatible with the arduino lcd library.

Thank you.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

I believe here is same display, with pinouts shown: http://carecoin.cl/2014/11/reciclaje-display-lcd-lmc-ss2a20-compatible-con-hd44780/

Seems standard HD44780 compatible display, 2x20 character matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If its truly custom it will be a challenge to find the pin-out. It looks like a standard HD44780 compatible 2*16 LCD. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller)

Pololu has a similar version with pin-out and other documentation like arduino code. https://www.pololu.com/product/772

[image: Pololu 2*16 LCD pin-out]

(Picture copyright of Pololu)